# How can I use tblwrite in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have data which are as the following :

```
rownames11{kk}=char(rownames1(1,j))----1x225
colnames11={'K_minus_t';'K_minus_d';'a';'b';'c';'Err'}----1X6
values11{kk}=[K_minus_t(j)   K_minus_d(l)  c  resnorm]------1x225 ( variabe C contain three Values)
end
end
tblwrite(values11,colnames11,rownames11,'functionfitting.txt')
```

I tried to put these data as table type txt files by using tblwrite 
when I implement the code I receive this massage:

Error using tblwrite (line 64)
Number of case names must equal number of data rows.

Error in lamm (line 96)
tblwrite(values11,colnames11,rownames11,'functionfitting.txt');

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will be grateful to you.

Comment: Sorry to ask but - what's the size of `resnorm` and what is `kk` in each loop, what's with the double bracket on `values11{kk}}`? So if you type `whos values11`, is it a 225x6? If it is a 6x225 I think you need to transpose. Finally, I think `tblwrite` takes a numeric matrix as values, not a cell, so maybe use `values(kk)` instead.

Comment: Thanks A. Klomp, I fixed the problem it was as you said I need to transpose the Values11